# c/ncurses - using getch with different program sections

Tags: c, keyboard, ncurses, getch

I am writing a simple ncurses program with a menu and different sections (create/view etc), all using the keyboard.  Currently I have one getkey routine and then switches to determine which section the keyboard input is for, like this:

```
ch = getch();

if(menu){
    switch(ch){
...

if(create){
    switch(ch){
...

if(view){
    switch(ch){
...
```

is this the best way to do this or should I have different getkey routines for each section (menu_getkey(), view_getkey() and so on) - what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This gets into a bit of design (and so might be a bit subjective), but I think your approach is fine. It allows you to handle common input logic close to the `getch()` before diving into specifics, and in general it's usually a good idea to handle events (e.g., keyboard input) in a single location if possible -- having multiple event loops tends to get messy as programs grow.

An equivalent way of writing it would be something like the following:

```
enum { MENU, CREATE, VIEW } input_focus = MENU;

...

void input_loop(void) {
    for (;;) {
        int ch = getch();

        /* Put common input logic here. */

        switch (input_focus) {
        case MENU:
            handle_menu_input(ch);
            break;

        case CREATE:
            handle_create_input(ch);
            break;

        case VIEW:
            handle_view_input(ch);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Your individual `case`s might have to have some more logic in them, but you get the idea.

Having short functions helps with readability. Modern compilers are smart enough to inline functions that are only called once (remove the function call and insert the code directly instead), so don't worry about performance. (And in case someone nit-picky reads this -- yes, it would require link time optimization for functions in different compilation units.)

Having a function pointer that you update to always point to the current input focus instead of having the `switch` would be another option, but it's overkill here. It's ~kinda what C++ does for virtual functions.